# How to convert a conventional Inkjet printer into a FDM resin 3D printer?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, resin, fdm

I searched about the subject in this website and could only find [this question here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15457/are-there-fdm-epoxy-resin-printers) asking "if there is an FDM Resin 3D printer", not how to build it.

---

The idea is to replace the inks for other fluids, such as resin and its hardener (and other fluids) and then add a Z axis "somehow".

---

The thing is: I couldn't find any tutorial on the subject.

The closest thing I could find was [this project here called Oasis 3DP, an open source powder and inkjet 3D printer](https://youtu.be/lIVdwP0RAN8), but the objects are incredibly fragile.

The other type was [this DIY that converts a creality 3D into a ink printer](https://hackaday.io/project/167446/gallery#2ba64e8a516cbe36d7f8b66cbd2d9b61), but it uses homemade nozzles actuated by piezoelectrics instead of a inkjet printer nozzle, and the results aren't as good as a conventional inkjet printers (not to insult the creator this is hella cool still).

Comment: If you were looking to do this as a "personal project" for self-improvement, I would say "probably". Otherwise, the price of a 3D printer has come down that even Micro Center is offering an Ender 3 for $99 to new customers.

Comment: Such principles exist, but we use metal powder or wire and lasers. If you can cure the resin that is dispensed this is a viable option, but be prepared to a long R&D trajectory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking for a kit.  There isn't one, and there isn't likely to ever be one, because conventional resin printing and FDM printing use completely different approaches to take advantage of respective material properties, and combining them is likely to get you the worst features of both rather than something better.

Additionally, ink jet printing and things based on it inherently get you brittle parts, and attempts to combine this with FDM methods won't fix that.

Without a kit, you are designing this from scratch.  This basically means you either need to be an engineer that can design solutions for all the problems up front, or you will be doing a lot of trial and error with repeated redesigns as you discover new problems -- not that an engineer wouldn't have the same issue without a lot of foresight.